# Closed points of projective space

Tags: algebraic-geometry, projective-space

Let $X = \Bbb P^n(\Bbb Z) = \mathrm{Proj}(\Bbb Z[X_0, ..., X_n])$ be the projective space over the integers. What is the set of its closed points?
Even for $n=1$, I'm not sure. I saw [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/97429/maximal-ideals-of-zx-y) question, but it doesn't look very easy to determine homogeneous maximal ideals, which give closed points in $X$ – I'm not sure to obtain all closed points like this, though.

My goal is to determined the zeta function of $X$ (what is its relation with the usual Riemann zeta). I'm not even sure what happens for $Y = \Bbb A^n(\Bbb Z)$, when $n >1$.

Comment: Any closed point of $X$ is a closed point of the closed subset $X_p\subset X$ where $X_p=\mathrm{Proj}(\mathbb{F}_p[X_0,\ldots, X_n])$ for some prime $p$.

Comment: @Mohan : if I assume your claim, is there an easy description of the homogeneous maximal ideals of $\Bbb F_p[X_0, X_1]$ (these are all the closed points, right?)? Thank you :-)

Comment: $p$ is allowed to vary of course.

Comment: Are you asking for homogeneous maximal ideals of $\mathbb{F}_p[X_0,X_1]$? There is only one- $(X_0,X_1)$. These are not closed points of $\mathbb{P}^1_{\mathbb{F}_p}$.